# SnappyData : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: apache-spark, caching, garbage-collection, gemfire, snappydata

I have 1.2GB of orc data on S3 and I am trying to do the following with the same :

1) Cache the data on snappy cluster [snappydata 0.9]

2) Execute a groupby query on the cached dataset

3) Compare the performance with Spark 2.0.0

I am using a 64 GB/8 core machine and the configuration for the Snappy Cluster are as follows:

```
$ cat locators
localhost

$cat leads
localhost -heap-size=4096m -spark.executor.cores=1

$cat servers
localhost -heap-size=6144m
localhost -heap-size=6144m
localhost -heap-size=6144m
localhost -heap-size=6144m
localhost -heap-size=6144m
localhost -heap-size=6144m
```

Now, I have written a small python script, to cache the orc data from S3 and run a simple group by query, which is as as follows :

```
from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappyContext
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('snappy_sample')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SnappyContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists my_schema.my_table using orc options(path 's3a://access_key:secret_key@bucket_name/path')")
sqlContext.cacheTable("my_schema.my_table")

out = sqlContext.sql("select *  from my_schema.my_table where (WeekId = '1') order by sum_viewcount desc limit 25")
out.collect()
```

The above script is executed using the following command:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] snappy_sample.py
```

and I get the following error :

```
17/10/04 02:50:32 WARN memory.MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_2_5 in memory! (computed 21.2 MB so far)
17/10/04 02:50:32 WARN memory.MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_2_0 in memory! (computed 21.2 MB so far)
17/10/04 02:50:32 WARN storage.BlockManager: Persisting block rdd_2_5 to disk instead.
17/10/04 02:50:32 WARN storage.BlockManager: Persisting block rdd_2_0 to disk instead.
17/10/04 02:50:47 WARN storage.BlockManager: Putting block rdd_2_2 failed due to an exception
17/10/04 02:50:47 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block rdd_2_2 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
17/10/04 02:50:47 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded


at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.build(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.build(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$next$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$next$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenRDD.compute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
17/10/04 02:50:47 ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-2,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.build(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.build(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$next$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$next$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenRDD.compute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
17/10/04 02:50:48 INFO snappystore: VM is exiting - shutting down distributed system
```

Apart from above error, how do I check if the data has been cached in snappy cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Firstly it does not look like you are connecting to the SnappyData cluster with the python script rather running it in local mode. In that case the JVM launched by the python script is failing with OOM as would be expected. When using python connect to SnappyData cluster in the "[smart connector](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/spark_installation_using_smart_connector/)" mode:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --conf snappydata.connection=locator:1527 snappy_sample.py
```

The host:port above is the locator host and port on which thrift server is running (1527 by default).

2) Secondly the example you have will just cache using Spark. If you want to use SnappyData, load into a column table:

```
from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappySession
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('snappy_sample')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
session = SnappySession(sc)

session.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists my_table using orc options(path 's3a://access_key:secret_key@bucket_name/path')")
session.table("my_table").write.format("column").saveAsTable("my_column_table")

out = session.sql("select *  from my_column_table where (WeekId = '1') order by sum_viewcount desc limit 25")
out.collect()
```

Also note the use of "SnappySession" rather than context which is deprecated since Spark 2.0.x. When comparing against Spark caching, you can use the "cacheTable" in a separate script and run against upstream Spark. Note that "cacheTable" will do the caching lazily meaning that first query will do the actual caching so first query run will be very slow with Spark caching but subsequent ones should be faster.

3) Update to the 1.0 release that has many improvements rather than using 0.9. You will also need to add [hadoop-aws-2.7.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3) and [aws-java-sdk-1.7.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4) to the "-classpath" in conf/leads and conf/servers (or put into jars directory of the product) before launching the cluster.